# PHP website with privileges structure

Tags: php, mysql, html, privileges

I am creating an Intranet with PHP. There will be different privileges for different users (admin, user etc).
I plan on using only PHP and a database in MySql with different tables.

I want to know which way is the simplest and "best suited" solution for writing the code of the Intranet, to separate "user" from "admin".

Is it to use one "index.php" and then use an if/else method for displaying content based on privileges? like this:

```
if ($priv == 'admin')
  display content for admin

else if ($priv == 'user')
  display content for user
```

OR should I have different files for different privileges, for example, use one file to first check the privileges and then open another page based on what privilege it is:

```
If "admin"
    OPEN index_admin.php
else if "user"
    OPEN index_user.php
```

Just need some advice on the direction to go here.

The intranet will be fairly simple, with a timereporting/timetracking function for employees of a business to report their times in.

Thanks

Comment: [The keyword you are looking for is ACL](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=acl+php)

Answer (score 1):

You've got the basic gist of what you need, but I'd recommend using self-processing pages. If you go down the redirect route, people can just access say, index_admin.php in their browser.

I'm assuming you're using a login system for this - if so, just set up a SQL table, and have a bool value for admin. So then we can do;

```
$sql = SELECT admin FROM users WHERE username = '{$user}';
$admin = mysqli_query($sql);

if ($admin == 1)
{
    // load the admin page
}

else
{
    // load the normal user page
}
```

You can make this more efficient by storing their admin status in a Session, in order to avoid constant SQL queries.

Hope this helps.

- Eoghan

Answer (score 1):

look into sessions and at the top of every page have this

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

To do stuff with session variables in your case

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['priv'] == $something) {
//Do stuff HERE
} else {
//And So Fourth
?>
```